# Parse Dashboard HTTPS error despite HTTPS is enabled

Tags: azure, parse-platform, parse-server

I installed complete Parse infrastructure on Azure using a dedicated template, I can not bypass the step with the Parse dashboard URL:

```
https//:myAppName.azurewebsites.net/parse-dashboard
```

The error is regarding: Parse Dashboard accessed via HTTPS when I pass the name and pwd input. How to proceed to my parse server and dashboard?

Comment: If you get the working solution, you could mark it to close the question, and let other people know the solution.

Comment: Thanks, How to close it?

Comment: Just mark your answer to let people know it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it to work thanks to @jimmy Azure master, so I would like to share as this might be painful and not documented anywhere in my experience. Accessing through the SCM site is not working anymore, initially it worked in year 2016 but they changed it two years ago. Finally it was the **index.js** and you need to paste in the setting for the insecure access as an object,then force https despite this setting in the app service configuration on azure exists, finally scale the app service plan from Free to Basic1 plan. restarting the Parse. 
You can check if the Parse is connected by saving an PFObject withClassName. Create a class in the ParseDashboard which will than save. If there is an error it will be in debugger -failure. Otherwise you are good to go!

Answer (score 1):

You are using an incorrect url to access the dashboard. In the [parse-server-azure wiki](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/parse-server-azure/wiki/Accessing-the-Parse-Dashboard), there is a description.

> The parse dashboard can be accessed at
>   https://:@.azurewebsites.net/parse-dashboard

You could also access it through the SCM site.

> If your Parse Server was created with the name contoso-mobile, then your Parse
>   Dashboard will be located at
>   https://contoso-mobile.scm.azurewebsites.net/parse-dashboard